# Hue Tap API compatibility

Tags: java, android, philips-hue

I'm considering buying some Philips Hue bulbs along with the Hue Tap to control them. I know there is an Android API from Philips but I would like to know if this API is also able to control the tap and is not only intended to be used with the Hue bridge.

Can anybody provide an answer to that? as I fail to find any conclusive information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make clear: A Tap with only lights does *NOT* work. You need a bridge. When you press the Tap it sends a signal to the bridge which then controls the lights.

Through the hue API you can configure (on the bridge) what should happen when you press a specific button on the Tap. Also you can view the last time the Tap was pressed and which button it was.

The hue developers site (free registration required) has an example for "programming" the Tap http://www.developers.meethue.com/hue-tap-scene-programming and an article about how to create a toggle button with it http://www.developers.meethue.com/how-create-hue-tap-toggle-button